# IONIC resizing HERE maps

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, mobile, maps

**RESIZING HERE MAPS-HELP**

I'm building an Ionic app with HERE maps. When I change my phones orientation I call m`aps.getViewPort().resize()`, but it doesn't work.I had set my div background where the map is to red and background is 100% width which is correct but maps don't scale.So I will be happy if you have some solutions.
**Picture**: Event when phones orientation is changed

Code of event:
[image]

Phone Screen :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a solution. The problem was that screenOrientation function was called faster than maps would resize so adding a 250ms delay worked fine for me.